# por que tengo problemas cuando subo mi proyecto de laravel al hosting

Tags: laravel

tengo un proyecto en Laravel y al momento de subirlo al hosting y hacer los cambios en el index y provider

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

public function register(){  $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){  return'/home/nombre-carpeta-hosting/public_html';  });}
```

y los cambios en el .env

```
APP_ENV=production, APP_DEBUG=false
```

y ejecute

```
composer dumpautoload
```

me da este error

> error de servidor interno
> El servidor encontró un error interno o una mala configuración y no pudo completar su solicitud.
> Póngase en contacto con el administrador del servidor en webmaster@000webhost.io para informarles de la hora en que ocurrió este error y las acciones que realizó justo antes de este error.
> Es posible que haya más información disponible sobre este error en el registro de errores del servidor.
> Además, se encontró un error 500 Internal Server Error al intentar utilizar un ErrorDocument para manejar la solicitud.

hice la prueba creando un nuevo proyecto de laravel sin nada y lo subi e hice los cambios y si me da la pantalla de inicio de laravel, pero con mi proyecto no

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Que tipo de hosting estás utilizando para tu proyecto? Tambien sería bueno que activaras el APP_DEBUG y lo pusieras en true para ver si es un problema de configuración de Laravel o del Servidor.

Comment: hola, estoy utilizando el 000webhost y como verificaría si es error de laravel o servidor?

Comment: En tu archivo .env a la linea que dice APP_DEBUG ponla en "true" para que laravel marque errores. En el servidor ahora tienes que ejecutar "COMPOSER UPDATE" para poder "instalar" sus funciones ahi. El "DUMPAUTOLOAD" solo sirve para limpiar el caché de composer.

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que si hayas puesto bien los path en el Index y el provider,
intenta eliminar el archivo config de bootstrap

Bootstrap->cache->config.php